# setlocale() для UTF8

Tags: php, locale

Подскажите, какую локаль использовать?

Есть проект (русскоязычный), написанный на PHP, у которого установлено: setlocale (LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8") и все бы ничего, если бы не один момент: при переводе переменной из формата double в string (например при генерации запроса в MySQL) приходится все время менять десятичный разделитель с запятой на точку: str_replace(',', '.', $double_value); Также, проблема с десятичным разделителем не редко встречается и в других местах скрипта.

В планах - изменить локаль.

Вариант 1 (Lite):

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

Вариант 2 (Hard):

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "С");
```

Я больше склоняюсь к варианту 2. То, что пользователям будут выводиться цифры с разделителем десятичной дроби в виде точки - не проблема.

Весь проект написан в UTF-8, везде используются функции mb_, так что параметр LC_CTYPE не должен повлиять на работу скрипта.

Дата везде передается в формате ISO Y-m-d h:i:s, а функция strftime() практически не используется, так что параметр setlocale() LC_TIME тоже не критичен. Да и офф. документация к strftime() не располагает к использованию этой функции:

> Ваша C-библиотека может не поддерживать все форматирующие параметры, в
>   этом случае они будут недоступны функции strftime(). Кроме того, не
>   все платформы поддерживают отрицательные метки времени, так что
>   поддерживаемый диапазон дат на этих платформах будет ограничен Эпохой
>   Unix. Это значит, что %e, %T, %R и %D (**а возможно и другие параметры**),
>   как и даты до Jan 1, 1970, не поддерживаются Windows, некоторыми
>   версиями Linux и некоторыми другими операционными системами.

Еще один плюс за использование второго варианта - локаль "C" используется в Drupal (setlocale (LC_ALL, "С");), и эта CMS хоть и не является образцом разработки приложения на PHP, но все же довольно распространена и проблем с её использованием на русскоязычных сайтах не наблюдается.

Предварительное тестирование не выявило багов, после смены локали на "С", но все равно, что-то может "всплыть" в самый не подходящий момент... На какие функции, etc еще следует обратить внимание при смене локали?

Comment: Есть функция http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что она быстрее str_replace по замене запятой на точку? :)

Comment: Нет, я хотел сказать, что эта функция предназначена именно для отображения отформатированного числа. А тест на скорость, если она так важна, можете провести самостоятельно.

Comment: А Вы знаете, что есть такая конструкция языка, как exit()? Если её поставить в начало скрипта, не придется заморачиваться с написанием кода - можете испытать на досуге :) Но к сожалению ни number_format(), ни exit() ни как не относятся к вопросу: "Подскажите, какую локаль использовать?".

Comment: `при переводе переменной из формата double в string ` ваши слова.